# Virtual attribute is not set before attr_encrypted uses said virtual attribute for encryption key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-attribute, attr-accessible, attr-accessor, attr-encrypted

When `encryption_key` is called by `attr_encrypted`, `:passphrase` hasn't been set. The encryption key ends up being a sha1 hash of the salt; it *should* be a sha1 hash of the passphrase and salt.

The salt is generated on creation and saved in the database.

How do I use the `:passphrase` virtual attribute in the encryption key?

Any suggestions?

For brevity I ommitted a bunch of code.

```rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'digest/sha1'
    attr_accessor :passphrase, :ssn
    attr_accessible :passphrase, :ssn
    attr_encrypted :ssn, :key => proc { |employee| "#{employee.encryption_key}" }

    def encryption_key
        unless salt?
            self.salt = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(generate_salt)
        end

        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([passphrase, self.salt].join)
    end
end

class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @employee = @parent.employees.new(params[:employee])
        if @employee.save
            redirect_to @parent
        else
            render action: "new"
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am assuming that `passphrase` is being returned to the controller inside `params`?  Also, where is `salt?` defined?

Comment: Correct: params[:employee][:passphrase]

Comment: And salt is a column in the database. So, if salt? returns nil, salt is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting ssn after passphrase and the other attributes

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ssn = params[:employee].delete(:ssn)
    @employee = @parent.employees.new(params[:employee])
    @employee.ssn = ssn
    if @employee.save
        redirect_to @parent
    else
        render action: "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect. Is there any way to either: set passphrase before ssn in the model, or delay attr_encrypted until attributes are set?

Comment: @pdjk I believe if you convert params[:employee] into an ordered hash and make sure that :passphrase appears before :ssn then it should work